# Java: how come this returns null?

Tags: java

This code does returns null InputStream as well as null URL. Why is that? I have my own class that I want to get the *actual* .class file as an InputStream to serialize to bytes[].

```
Class clazz = String.class;

String className = clazz.getName(); System.out.println(className);
URL url = clazz.getResource(className);
if( url != null )
{
  String pathName = url.getPath(); System.out.println(className);
}

InputStream inputStream = clazz.getResourceAsStream(className);
if(inputStream != null )
{
  System.out.println(inputStream.available());
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768256/java-class-file-and-java-lang-class

Comment: @Donnie: please note the answer ChssPly76 gives me was actually incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need the context's classloader. Secondly, you need to replace the dots `.` in classname by forward slashes `/` and suffix the `.class` extension to identify the real path.

So this one should work:

```
String name = String.class.getName().replace(".", "/") + ".class";
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(name);
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name);
```

**Edit:** I should have added, `inputStream.available()` is **not** the way to learn about the file size. It just returns the amount of bytes which are available to read *without* blocking. With other words, the return value should never be treated as consistent. If you want to get the actual length, you'll really need to read the entire stream.

Comment: Copied, pasted, tested --> works! Three words: You are awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Oh thank you for telling me about the available() too! I thought available() was the size of the .class file. Thanks again for your details!

Comment: +1, though a simpler way (which I meant to write in the other question but messed up) is to use `clazz.getResourceAsStream(clazz.getSimpleName() + ".class")`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm not sure if you can get the actual .class file as a resource.

Secondly `getName()` will include the package and calling `Class.getResource()` will assume the path is relative to the class if it does not start with a slash.

You need to replace the '.'s in the class name with slashes  and prepend a slash for `getResource()` to work correctly.

If you can get .class files as a resource you'd also need to append '.class' to the class name when calling `getResource()`